# Finding the mean from input

Tags: python

my 6th grade teacher asked me to code a program in python that input any amount of a number and it outputs the mean so i tried and theirs a problem with the print statement here's the code.i even tried to replace the float(b) statements to float(1) statements but that didn't work either

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements :"))

b =  input("\nEnter the numbers :")

sum = (float(b)+float(b)+float(b) / float(n) 

print("\nThe mean is -",sum())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give space separated input here :

```
input = list(map(float ,input('Enter number of elements : ').split(' '))) 
mean = sum(input)/len(input) 
print(mean)
```

**: Output :**
Enter number of elements : 10 20 30
20.0

Comment: I believe this should use the "Enter the numbers" prompt rather than "Enter number of elements".

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this.
I assumed you wanted the arithmetic mean and not the geometric one, so the first thing to do is to get the number of values the user wants to input and store it in the variable `n`. The you iterate over a range `n` and you sum the inputs to `k`.
The you divide `k` by `n`.

```
n, k = int(input("Enter number of elements:")), 0

for i in range(n):
    k += float(input("Enter value number {}".format(i+1)))

k /= n

print(k)
```

if you want to use the "cool" way you can do something like this:

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
k = sum([float(input("Enter value number {}".format(i+1))) for i in range(n)]) / n
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an syntax error and logical error in this code.

You haven't closed the opening bracket, It should be like this

```
sum = (float(b)+float(b)+float(b)) / float(n)
```

If you want to calculate the mean of 3 values why are you adding the same value for three times here

```
(float(b)+float(b)+float(b))
```

Insted of using same values you can get each values from for loop like this

```
for i in range(3):
  num = float(input())
  total += num
```